# cannot start rails server -> cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2 (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rails application cannot start because mysql2 load error.
I have tried many solutions, But none can't fix the problem.
Even the rake command can't be executed.

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2
```

My gemfile is:

```
ruby '2.5.1'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.4'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.5.2'
```

Bundle installed successfully. Mysql installed correctly. Yet the error occurs on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, uninstall and reinstall with the following command:

```
gem install mysql2
```

If this is not working, you can try adding the following to your `mysql_config`:

```
gem install mysql2 -v 0.4.4 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6/5.6.42/bin/mysql_config --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```